# how to add 2 values together using angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my html

```
<div data-ng-app="">

<p>Enter a value: <input type="text" ng-model="valueOne" value=""></p>
<p> the first value you typed is: <span data-ng-bind="valueOne"></span> </p>

<p> Age: <input type="text" ng-model="valueTwo" value=""></p>
<p> the first value you typed is: <span data-ng-bind="valueTwo"></span> </p>



<p> The sum of the values is: {{addValues()}}</p>
</div>
```

this is my JS

```
<script>

function addValues($scope){

$scope.Math = window.Math;
valueOne + valueTwo;
}
</script>
```

what needs doing differently to get the required answer? so far I can only get string concatenation to work but I would like to be able to give me the answer 6 when I enter 2 and 4 rather than the current answer it is giving which is 24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div data-ng-app="" data-ng-controller="addValues">

<p>Enter a value: <input type="text" data-ng-model="valueOne" value="0"></p>
<p> the first value you typed is: <span data-ng-bind="valueOne"></span> </p>

<p> Age: <input type="text" data-ng-model="valueTwo" value="0"></p>
<p> the first value you typed is: <span data-ng-bind="valueTwo"></span> </p>



<p> The sum of the values is: {{sum()}}</p>
</div>


<script>

function addValues($scope){
    $scope.valueOne=0;
    $scope.valueTwo=0;
     $scope.sum = function() {
            return parseInt($scope.valueOne)+parseInt($scope.valueTwo);
        }


}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @BlueShark are you getting any error.i have posted the entire page just try to create new page and past this code and run and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

first your function needs return statement which should return result,
also where are you defining this function, where from exactly did you get this $scope. Because if you want to use function like that you need to bind it to $scope like $scope.addValues = function(){}

so for example inside of your angular controller you would have

```
$scope.addValues = function() {
    return $scope.valueOne + $scope.valueTwo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try to parse values to integer before adding?

```
parseInt(valueOne) + parseInt(valueTwo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but you could change the last part to :

```
<p>The sum of the values is: {{valueOne*1 + valueTwo*1}}</p>
```

This will force the `valueOne` and `ValueTwo` to be expressed as numbers to **add**.

Or, set up a controller...

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.controller('ctrlAdd', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.valueOne = 0;
      $scope.valueTwo = 0;

      $scope.result = function(){
        return parseInt($scope.valueOne) + parseInt($scope.valueTwo);
      }
    }]);
```

and change the HTML...

```
   <body>
  <div data-ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrlAdd">
    <p>Enter a value:
      <input type="text" ng-model="valueOne" value="" />
    </p>
    <p>the first value you typed is: <span data-ng-bind="valueOne"></span>
    </p>
    <p>Age:
      <input type="text" ng-model="valueTwo" value="" />
    </p>
    <p>the first value you typed is: <span data-ng-bind="valueTwo"></span>
    </p>
    <p>The sum of the values is: {{result()}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wO1Fke9UmjN48Zh8rPOV?p=preview)

Comment: i really thought this was gonna work and but it just returns this.
<p> The sum of the values is: {{result()}}</p>

Comment: It seems you're not referencing `AngularJS` then? do you have a reference to the script file? simple way to check...just place `{{2+4}}` in the html and see what the output is.